# Xcode 4.2 - certificates ok, but "There is no codesign_wrapper executable. Please reinstall the Xcode developer tools." appears

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, code-signing

I select "Build to Archive" in XCode 4.2, and the following error appears:

```
Validate "/Users/merlin/Motivapps/DerivedData/GoalWorkshop2-gzesusxljzqjkmbznfkkmylstlca/ArchiveIntermediates/GoalWorkshop2/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Goal Wshop.app"
    cd /Users/merlin/Motivapps/GoalWorkshop2
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.application
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation "/Users/merlin/Motivapps/DerivedData/GoalWorkshop2-gzesusxljzqjkmbznfkkmylstlca/ArchiveIntermediates/GoalWorkshop2/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Goal Wshop.app"

2011-06-10 17:10:48.879 Validation[15683:607] *** Warning: Defaulting to the standard codesign tool
warning: There is no codesign_wrapper executable. Please reinstall the Xcode developer tools. (-19058)
Unable to validate your application. - (null)
```

The same configuration worked well with previous XCode, and I just double checked - code sign certificates are valid. Suggestions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just change your selected Xcode version like this:

```
$ xcode-select -print-path 
/Xcode42
$ sudo xcode-select -switch /Xcode402
Password:
$ xcode-select -print-path           
/Xcode402
```

Comment: i resolve problem from this answer :) in my case sudo xcode-select -switch /Developer

Comment: it works, of course assuming that you installed Xcode 4.2 in a different folder than 4.02 :)

Comment: THANK YOU. This totally saved my bacon.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I found was to remove XCode 4.2beta from the system, and reinstall the previous version - it helped. Beta versions are not meant to build release builds I guess.

Comment: I ran kodz solution with the Terminal.app and the path for Xcode was that for the beta version, so I changed it to the main Xcode path and I'll wait to see if that worked, I would like to avoid removing the beta because I am using it to try some new things with...